# Plane rendering in render preview but not when performing an actual render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I'm trying to render a forest with a river. The terrain is basically a plane with tree as particles. The trees and water are redering as they should but the land is not rendering.

I'm able to see the everything correctly in the preview render tab.

I'm using cycles render engine for rendering.

The link to my blender file is https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Te_Zb7Lwh6hWL2xsyqKG_MV18AAZ1bqP/view?usp=sharing

This is the preview screenshot

[image]

This is the rendered image

[image]

Comment: Check if there are any hidden objects (which are only enabled for rendering).

Comment: @Leander, there aren't any hidden objects..

Comment: Any Displacement? (Your file isn't accessible to the public).

Comment: @Leander Oh, sorry about that,, I've made it public. 
I had applied done some sculpting to make the terrain. Then I applied all transformation to it..

Comment: You disabled *Properties > Object > Instancing > **Render Instancer*** for the "Land" object. Enable it!.

Comment: @Leander wow,, thankyou so much, Its working now !

Answer (score 0):

As @Leander said in the comment, I had disabled rendering in the objects property. Enabling it worked.